# At what rate is the angle $\theta$ changing when 10 ft. of rope is out?

Tags: calculus

A dinghy is pulled toward a dock by a rope from the bow through a ring on the dock 6 ft. above the bow. The rope is hauled in a rate of 2 ft/s.

At what rate is the angle $\theta$ changing when 10 ft. of rope is out?

[image: boat_approaching_dock]

I understand related rates problems, but the trig and angle part of the question is confusing me. How do I solve this?

Comment: Draw a picture. How are the 6, 10 and $\theta$ related? Which derivative corresponds to 2 ft/s?

Comment: The height of the dock is fixed.  So the length of the rope $r = 6\sec\theta,\frac{dr}{dt} = 2 ft/s =  6 \sec\theta \tan\theta \frac{d\theta}{dt}$

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I got $d\theta/dt = (1/3)(cos\theta cot\theta) = (1/3)(6/10)(6/8) = 3/20 \theta$.

Comment: Is $\theta$ the angle the rope forms with the water or the angle the rope forms with the side of the dock?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Here's a picture for a better explanation: [Page 7](http://www.firelandsschools.org/Downloads/RelatedRates.pdf). I believe the answer to your question is the side of the dock.

Comment: Do you understand the solution in the linked document?

Comment: The solution in the linked document isn't entirely the same as the question asked here differs from both of the questions in the document, but yes I do understand the solution.

Comment: One thing is to check the _direction_ in which things are changing. The dinghy gets closer to the dock as the rope is pulled, so the angle gets smaller. Therefore the derivative you calculate should end up being a negative number.

Answer (score 1):

You have the relation $\cos\theta=\dfrac{6}{r}$ so $-\sin(\theta)\dfrac{d\theta}{dt}=-\dfrac{6}{r^2}\dfrac{dr}{dt}$, or

\begin{equation}
\sin(\theta)\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{6}{r^2}\frac{dr}{dt}
\end{equation}

When $r=10$ we know that $\dfrac{dr}{dt}=-2$ and $\sin(\theta)=\dfrac{8}{10}=\dfrac{4}{5}$ so

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{5}{4}\cdot\frac{6}{100}(-2)=-0.15 \text{ per seconds}
\end{equation}

**Corrected** as per comment by @TonyK

Comment: $\sin \theta=\frac{8}{10}$, not $\frac{6}{10}$.

Comment: @TonyK Thanks for catching that error.